# Meaning of "harvesting your eyeballs via electronic mail"

Tags: meaning

A few years ago I subscribed to the "Little White Lies” newsletter and in their latest edition there is a sentence I don't understand:

> We understand that, when it comes to *harvesting your eyeballs via electronic mail*, you don’t have a massive amount of time, especially during the festive season.

I don't understand the expression: "harvesting your eyeballs via electronic mail". I actually understand the meaning, but it is more like a guess than a real understanding.

Comment: It's bad writing, IMO. Don't use it as a model.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Merriam Webster dictionary:

[**Harvest**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/harvest)

> 1
> c: to remove or extract (something, such as living cells, tissues, or organs) from culture (see CULTURE entry 1 sense 3) or from a living or recently deceased body especially for transplanting

Here “harvesting your eyeballs” is used figuratively, to mean: catch and sustain your attention, more specifically, the act of you “reading” their newsletter.

Comment: I think it means to "hurt" them.

Comment: Why’s that? I believe the context supports my conclusion. @Lambie